# Book series about an enhanced female agent who is assigned as a bodyguard to a male musician

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking for a book series that I read over 10+ years ago. Here's what I remember:

The female character is enhanced ( due to injury? ); she's an agent, possibly for the government. One of her assignments is to bodyguard the male character, whom I believe is a musician. I believe his name begins with a 'Z' ( Zeb for Zebulon or Zeph or Zeke ); I'm leaning toward Zeke. He's more than just human.

I feel like the author is female. Definitely more than one book. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure it is "young adult"? @Eike answer is spot on, but the book can be quite graphic sometimes... ;)

Comment: I wasn't sure about the male character's name (way off with Zeke) let alone the rating so my apologies for YA rating and thank you for the answer Eike

Comment: @Kat if you're happy with the answer, you should see a checkmark next to it that you can click to accept.

Answer (score 19):

In [Justina Robsons "Keeping It Real"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_It_Real_(novel)) (2006), first installment of her Quantum gravity series, cyborg operative Lila Black is protecting the Elven rock musician Zal.

Background to the series is that the explosion of a quantum bomb has opened doorways between Earth and magical realms with elves, demons etc (despite the name of the series, the mention of the "quantum explosion" is basically the only mention of quantum gravity or anything related).

[image: Keeping it real, Amherst NY 2006]

Very dense read, a bit of an acquired taste, but still rather entertaining.